# Positionning an image depending on the page size

Tags: html, css

I have an image with an empty center. I would like to place a spinning image right in the middle of this empty image.

Please take a look here: http://www.prezzio.net/

**The problem is when the page is resized the image is also resized and the spinning image is no more positionned in the empty area of the image.** I don't know if this is feasable but I would like to have the spinning image to be always positionned in the empty (cicle) of the image. Maybe by playing with top, left, width in percentage on the spinning image ?

Possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spinning graphic has

```
.spin {
position:absolute;
top: 29%;
left: 33%
}
```

But if the image isn't resizing (it isn't), you need to give it absolute `top` and `left` co-ordinates (and dimensions), not relative ones:

```
.spin {
position:absolute;
top: 260px;
left: 425px;
width:196px;
height:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could play with the CSS `@media` rule to change things depending of the window size. For example, for windows up to 800px wide, you could define:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) { /* up to 800px wide */
    #myimage {
        position: absolute;
        top: 29%;
        right: 33%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 801px) { /* 801px and above */
    #myimage {
        position: absolute;
        top: <another value>;
        right: <another value>;
    }
}
```

Of course, a better approach would be to have an autoresizable container for your image (a `div`) with `position: relative;` and `max-width: <the width of your image>;` and then position stuff inside it absolutely.